# Get containerView of ViewController inside of PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a problem with adding actions to buttons a ViewController inside of my PageViewController.

So far, I've done it like this for this specific VC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(disableSwipe(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "disableSwipe"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enableSwipe(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "enableSwipe"), object: nil)

        if let secondViewController = viewControllerList.first as? HomeViewController {
            self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            secondViewController.iconPlus.action = #selector(addData(_:))
            secondViewController.buttonReminder.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToReminder(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            secondViewController.buttonSettings.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToSettings(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }
```

This approach worked fine, but now that I've added a ContainerView, which contains a TableViewController with buttons, I understandably get the following error:

> Value of type 'HomeViewController' has no member 'buttonReminder'

How can I access the containerView's buttons to execute actions from the PageViewController?

**Edit, containerView - TableViewController:**

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTimeline: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonReminder: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonLeasing: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonSettings: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

```
secondViewController.loadViewIfNeeded()
let res = secondViewController.children.first as! MenuTableViewController
```

To make it more clear: I've got my HomeViewController which is part of a RootPageViewController. This HomeViewController contains a ´ViewContainer` to display a TableViewController with buttons.

Comment: post code of `HomeViewController`

Comment: @Sh_Khan The only thing relevant in HomeViewController might be this reference: `@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
if let secondViewController = viewControllerList.first as? HomeViewController {

     secondViewController.loadViewIfNeeded()  // not recommended
     let res = secondViewController.children.first as! NestedVC
     res.button..........
}
```

What is better is to make the `HomeVC` a `UIViewController` child and add the buttons and a `UITableView` for 1 direct access instead of the above nested access

Comment: Thanks. Which ViewController do you mean by `vc` and by  `NestedVC` - do you mean the TableViewController's class?

Comment: see edit with vc i meant secondViewController / homevc and NestedVC = TableViewController's class

Comment: I get the following error: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key containerView.`

Comment: if you have that crash then you need to hook the view `containerView` properly , verify outlet connection for the homeVC